# Opencv python detection of camera is covered with transparent glass or plastic or incoming frames are focused

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, opencv3.0

I'm trying to detect camera is out of focus or not, with blurriness. When i'm executing this code the camera is open and live and suppose any moving object comes in focus area then it calculate its blurriness and displays camera is defocused with blurriness %. My problem is suppose i put a transparent glass or plastic on camera then it not detected. How can i do it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#capturing video frame and applying background subtraction
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
ret, frame = cap.read()
fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

#calculating laplacian variation
def laplacian_variation(image):
    if image.ndim == 3:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur_map = cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F)
    score = np.var(blur_map)
    return score

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (frame is None):
        print("camera is blocked")
        break
    else:
        a = 0
        bounding_rect = []
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        fgmask = cv2.erode(fgmask, kernel, iterations=5)
        fgmask = cv2.dilate(fgmask, kernel, iterations=5)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        #taking threshold, calling laplacian_variation and calculating 
        #contours
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(frame, 10, 50, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        fm = laplacian_variation(frame)
        _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                         cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for i in range(0, len(contours)):
            bounding_rect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contours[i]))

        for i in range(0, len(contours)):
            if bounding_rect[i][2] >= 40 or bounding_rect[i][3] >= 40:
                a = a + (bounding_rect[i][2]) * bounding_rect[i][3]

            #check if focus measure(fm) is less than threshold then 
            #camera is out out of focus or incoming images is blurry
            if (fm < thresh.all() or a >= int(frame.shape[0]) * 
                                          int(frame.shape[1]) / 3):
                cv2.putText(frame, "defocused", (5, 30), 
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 
                            255), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, "{}: {:.2f}".format('blurriness', 
                            fm), (5, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                            0.8, (0, 0, 255),3)

            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff == 27:
        break

#release the camera and destroy all opened windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```